# NuGet Package icon is not updated

Tags: icons, nuget, teamcity, nuget-server, nuspec

We are using Team city as an internal NuGet repository. 
I have added an icon url to my nuspec file and placed the icon file on an IIS with Content Browsing enabled. And the icon shows up in the NuGet Manager in Visual Studio.

Now I want to update the icon, so I thought I would just need to update the icon on IIS, but the icon is not updated. I have also tried to build a new version of the package through Team city, but the icon is not updated.

Is there some sort of caching going on? When is the icon retrieved from the url? Is it on packaging or is it the Package Manager?

Comment: For some reason, the icons were updated the day after.